# Vagrant -- SSL failures from apache2 until manually restarted

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, vagrant

I'm using Apache and mod_ssl with a self-signed certificate inside a Vagrant VM.

When I initially bring the Vagrant box up, web requests result in these types of error messages in my log and SSL errors in my browser:

```
[Fri Jan 31 03:45:06 2014] [notice] child pid 7913 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Jan 31 03:45:08 2014] [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(1) failed in child 7916 for worker proxy:reverse
```

If after the Vagrant box is started, I run "sudo service apache2 restart" web requests start running.

The weird thing is that I have that "sudo service apache2 restart" in my bootstrap file, and it's going off when Vagrant comes up, but my requests still give SSL fails.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Do you provision the box with puppet/ansible/chef ?

This kind of error occurs if you start a ssl-vhost without the certificates (or the complete chain).
Restarting apache service is the only solution to get the certificate/config working.

To confirm this check your vhost apache logs or the default apache logs. (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`)